# Fading out JavaScript "modal window" when background is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a modal-like window in CSS that I fade in with JavaScript. The HTML is like this:

```
<div class="whiteout">
<div class="modal">
    <a class="modal-close" title="Close"></a>
    // modal window content
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is like this:

```
.whiteout {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff; 
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 200;
    border: 12px solid #666;
    border: 12px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

I'm using jQuery to show the modal window when I click a link, with the "whiteout" background, and I want it to fade out when I click the background.

```
$('.share-link').click( function() {
    $('.whiteout').fadeIn();
    return false;
} );
$('.whiteout').click( function() { // click the background
    $(this).fadeOut();
} );
$('.modal-close').click( function() { // close button on the modal window
    $('.whiteout').fadeOut();
} );
```

However, it fades out whenever I click the modal window, as well as the background, because technically that is inside the "whiteout" element. Is it possible to stop that happening when I click inside the `.modal` element?

Comment: Not putting this as an answer, since I haven't *really* looked into your specific case: 
$('whiteout').click( function(event) { 
    if (this == event.target) { $(this).fadeOut(); } 
});
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.whiteout').click( function(e) { // click the background
    if(e.target == this)
       $(this).fadeOut();
} );
```

Comment: How about `if (e.target == this)` instead? Seems more direct and addresses the possibility of there being more than one class applied to the overlay.

Comment: @gilly3: Agreed (now that someone *did* look into the specific case). `hasClass()` would be slightly better, but `if (e.target == this)` wins for showing the intent best - since it's the standard way of checking if an event is bubbled in jQuery (and is probably slightly faster, as if anyone cared).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing might be to move the whiteout div to the end of the body, entirely outside the content area. With the right CSS, the whiteout element can live anywhere in the DOM but still achieve the right effect.

As an example, take a look at how [jQuery UI’s dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) works, it does almost exactly this.